# "OleDBException was unhandled. Data type mismatch in criteria expression." in AutoNumber (id). What to do?

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, exception, oledb

I have this codes below, but I don't know what is the reason why it was always having errors. Here is the code:

```
private void btn_acart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
            string[] product = new string[7];
            string[] select = new string[2];
            int[] num = new int[5];
            foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.SelectedItems)
            {
                select[1] = item.Text;
                string str = "SELECT * FROM [lblProduct] WHERE [prod_id]='"+select[1]+"'";
                com = new OleDbCommand(str, con);
                read = com.ExecuteReader();
                while (read.Read())
                {
                    product[1] = (read["prod_id"].ToString());
                    product[2] = (read["prod_name"].ToString());
                    product[3] = (read["prod_price"].ToString());
                    product[4] = (read["prod_stock"].ToString());
                    this.listView2.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { product[1], product[2], product[3], product[4] }));
                    cartitems++;

                    num[1] = int.Parse(product[4]);
                    num[2] = int.Parse(txt_items.Text);
                    string strg = "UPDATE lblProduct SET prod_stock='"+(num[1] - num[2]+"' WHERE prod_id='"+product[1]+"'");
                    com = new OleDbCommand(strg, con);
                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        loaddbase();
        con.Close();
        txt_items.Text = "0";
    }
}
```

[image]
What should I do? What should I change? Please help! The error is always repeating at the read = com.ExecuteReader();

**Access Database:**
Format: (Field Name - Data Type)
prod_id - AutoNumber
prod_name - Text
prod_price - Text
prod_stock - Text

Are there anything to change in the database?

Comment: What is the datatype of the field _prodid_ on your database table? I bet it is a numeric integer. Then why do you pass a string in the where clause? But more important is, why you don't use parameters instead of string concatenations?

Comment: @Steve actually I am just a newbie in creating such system. If you won't mind, what should I do then? Btw, I edited the question and written the database informations.

Comment: Yes I see it. First, a value used to query a numeric field doesn't require the single quotes around the value. Second, better use parameters

Comment: @Steve So, shall it be `string str = "SELECT * FROM lblProduct WHERE prod_id = " +select[1]+""`?

Comment: Well, yes, but your error message is not what you have written in the title of the question. Please be more precise.